# Tomcat not shown on the Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to install tomcat sysdeo plugin for Eclipse, but I ran into some problems before I even got to the setting/configuration part of the plugin.

When I run my Eclipse, under Preferences, I do not see tomcat section.
Besides downloading the tomcat, I know I'm missing some steps here to show it on the Eclipse.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?
I just want to see tomcat under Preferences so that I can change or set configuration stuffs via Eclipse.

Thanks!!!

Comment: whââât ? Could you examine your error log file and check if there is any message in it which I could analyze ?

Comment: The error log file can help and you will find it in: [eclipse-workspace]\.metadata\.log (wherever you put your workspace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. Found out that something was wrong with my Eclipse.

I had to download a fresh version of Eclipse and install the plugin again.

Everything worked fine after.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 3):

What version of eclipse are you using here ?

If this is eclipse3.4 or 3.5Mx, I recommend to download [tomcatPluginV321.zip](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html) and uncompressed it in your `[eclipse]`<sup>(*)</sup>`\dropins\` directory (dropins, not plugins: since the [p2 update system](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started), do not put external plugins into the plugins directories -- like this [tutorial suggests](http://www.eclipse-blog.org/eclipse-ide/tomcat-in-eclipse-sysdeo-tomcat-plug-in.html) --, always dropins)

<sup>(`*`)</sup> `[eclipse]` being your installation directory for eclipse, containing `eclipse.exe`.

You should then have:

```
[eclipse]\dropins\com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat_3.2.1\...
```

Relaunch (even without the `-clean` option), and there you should have it: tomcat menu on the main menu bar.

I just did it, and "it just works"<sup>TM</sup>

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse-blog.org](https://www.eclipse-blog.org/wp-content/uploads/2007/04/tomcat-options.PNG))</sub>

Comment: whââât ? Could you examine your error log file and check if there is any message in it which I could analyze ?

Answer (score 0):

After installing the plugin, you should restart eclipse with the `-clean` parameter. Maybe not doing that caused your install to be incomplete.

Comment: I've actually done that. However, in order to display the plugin's taskbar, I've been guided to go to Preferences (or Window -> Customize Perspective... -> Commands). I am following the sysdeo website's instruction. They don't explain what I need to do before I install the plugin.